# How to align offices in excel based on the number of months it has been open?

Tags: excel

The data I have has multiple offices (600+) with different opening dates as the years have gone on. However, we frequently need to do analysis where we line up everything based on how long it has been open. For example, what is the average revenue performance of an office in it's first 6 months of opening. We have manually been lining up every office so that each month 1 is together, but there has to be an easier way?

Data example:

**Offices & Open Dates:**
Office X-      03/07/2012
Office Y-      5/19/2014
Office Z-      12/01/2009

I need the revenue to line up as follows

**Column A**
Office X
Office Y
Office Z

**Column B - Month 1 Revenue**
Revenue for 03/2012
Revenue for 05/2014
Revenue for 12/2009

**Column C - Month 2 Revenue**
Revenue for 04/2012
Revenue for 06/2014
Revenue for 01/2010

**Column D - Month 3 Revenue**
Revenue for 05/2012
Revenue for 07/2014
Revenue for 02/2010

etc.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: To answer this we need to know how your revenue data is stored and also how the office opening date is stored or do you just take the 1st month revenue date as the office opening.  I assume that you would need to sort your revenue data by date and then use an index small function that can extract the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. revenue values for each office.  You don't need to show your data but structure and whether you have a unique reference for each office.

Answer (score 0):

My comment mentioned using index and small in an array formula to extract the data if the revenue data is sorted by date.  Array formulas can be tricky and having to keep the data sorted is a pain so I've had another idea.

If you are able to add a new column in your revenue data, preferably before the revenue value, then you can create an id that can be used with a simple vlookup to extract the data you need.

Let's assume that your office name is in column A, your revenue date is in column C and revenue value is in column D

You can use the formula below to create a unique id for each revenue month

```
=A1 & " MONTH " & countifs($A$1:$A$20,A1,$C$1:$C$20,"<="&C1)
```

=A1 gets the office name to use in the id and then we add the text " MONTH " to the office name.

The countifs part counts all the revenue dates with the same office name that are the same or older (so it counts itself and returns 1 for the oldest then 2 for the second oldest etc.)

We end up with an id column something like this

Office Name 1 MONTH 1
 Office Name 2 MONTH 1
 Office Name 1 MONTH 2

As you have 600 offices it could be a little bit slow so you could copy and paste as values once the formula has done it's work.

Now that you have this id column you can use it to extract the revenue data by month using a vlookup and if you have a list of offices and headings MONTH 1, MONTH 2, MONTH 3 along the top then you can automate the creation of the vlookup required to extract the data you need.

So if the office names are in column F and the headings start in column G the formula below can be autofilled across and down to extract the required values.  Notice that the $F column for the names has the column locked and the heading value in G$1 has the row locked because the $F2 & G$1 create the id "Office 1 MONTH 1"

```
=iferror(vlookup($F2 & G$1,$B$1:$D$20,3,false),"")
```

Comment: Our data is in a cloud based system that we can run reporting off of by using filters including time. Each office number is unique. Open date is a separate feature from each month of revenue. It is a different field in the table it is stored in. I understand what you're saying with doing an index. I figured it'd be something along those lines of creating helper reference cells and going from there. Thank you for your help